# can copy constructor be a conversion operator?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Test
{
        private:
                int x,y;
        public:
                Test () {
                        cout <<" Inside Constructor "<<endl;
                        x=100;
                }   
                explicit Test (const Test & t)
                {   
                        cout <<"Inside Copy Constructor "<<endl;
                        x = t.x;
                }   
                void display()
                {   
                        cout <<" X is "<<x<<endl;
                }   

};



int main (int argc, char ** argv){
  Test t;
  t.display(); 

 cout <<"--- Using Copy constructor "<<endl;
 Test t2(t);
 t2.display (); 

 Test t3=t2;
 t3.display (); 

}
```

Test (const Test & t)  -> is a copy constructor

**Question:**

Is the same used as a "Conversion Operator" ?
Test t3  = t2     [ Here copy Constructor is treated as a conversion operator]

I am not sure if my understanding is correct?. Kindly correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: This code has no conversion operator anywhere in it.  Not even a conversion constructor nor a conversion assignment.  In fact, there's no conversions in your code at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Test t3=t2;
```

Should never compile, if `copy c-tor` is `explicit`.

n3337 12.3.1/3

> A non-explicit copy/move constructor (12.8) is a converting constructor. An implicitly-declared copy/move
> constructor is not an explicit constructor; it may be called for implicit type conversions.

This quote appears to following question: [Implicit copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428308/implicit-copy-constructor)

So, in your case, it's not conversion constructor.

Comment: what if i remove the explicit?, then is it treated as a conversion operator?

Comment: @Whoami as conversion c-tor, not conversion operator.

Comment: sorry. :). So, copy constructor is also a conversion constructor if not explicit?

Comment: @Whoami it may be used for implicit conversions, yeah.

Comment: So, what understand is: implicit copy constructor is not an 'explicit copy constructor', and implicit copy constructor is a converting constructor, and it may be used for 'implicit type conversion'. KIndly correct me if my understanding is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the term *conversion* implies two different types : *source type* and *destination type*.

Copy-constructor, by definition, involves only one type : source type and destination type are same. So it cannot be called a conversion function.

Comment: Not true, according to standard.

Comment: Sorry. I'm wrong, it really can not be called conversion function, but can be used for conversions.

Comment: Your answer is correct, that you cannot call it conversion function, but copy-constructor can be used for implicit type conversions.

Comment: @ForEveR: You're wrong. Copy-constructor is not used for any  conversion. It is the single-argument function is *used* for the conversion.

Comment: Look at my answer.) There is quote there.

Comment: @ForEveR: I know it sounds weird, but the quote doesn't make sense to me, honestly. I mean, it uses the "incorrect" words to describe it.

Comment: May be you are right. Standard has no examples for this quote.

Comment: @ForEveR: Why I think it doesn't make sense to me is that in implicit conversions the parameter gets converted into the class type **before** the copy-constructor is called, because as we know the copy-constructor of class `T` takes argument of type `T const&` (usually); it doesn't take argument of `U`.  So the copy-constructor technically doesn't "convert" anything as such.

Comment: Taking in acoount answer to my question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428308/implicit-copy-constructor#12428391 - it's really conversion constructor.

Answer (score -3):

when you use T t3 = t2. It will call the assignment operator which you haven't define it.

Comment: t3 = t2; would call assignment, T t3 = t2; doesn't.

Comment: You needn't define a assignment operator in this case.