# Implicit copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, implicit-conversion

Quote from n3337 12.3.1/3

> A non-explicit copy/move constructor (12.8) is a converting
>   constructor. An implicitly-declared copy/move constructor is not an
>   explicit constructor; it may be called for implicit type conversions.

Quote from ANSI ISO IEC 14882 2003

> A non-explicit copy-constructor (12.8) is a converting constructor. An
>   implicitly-declared copy constructor is not an explicit constructor;
>   it may be called for implicit type conversions.

I have no ideas, how `copy-constructor` can be used for `implicit` type `conversions`. And if it's misprint/error in standard, why it's not corrected since C++03 standard? Any links and examples (if we can use it for `type conversions`) are really appreciated.

Comment: +1 for asking the question. Even I had this doubt after reading the Standard text quoted in your answer in the other topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A copy constructor can convert from an object of a derived type by slicing it:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};

B b;
A a = b; // uses A::A(A const&) to convert B to A
```

Comment: Which makes copy constructors inherently dangerous when ignored.  Good practice is that unless you want them, you should prevent default  Copy Constructors and Assignment Operators.  Prior to C++11, this could be done with declaring them private and not implementing them (it helps to comment that you are doing this).  In C++11, you can replace the implementation with `= delete`.

Comment: @JonathanSeng: That's one approach. I prefer to avoid inheritance from non-abstract types, so that slicing isn't possible. There's rarely a good reason to inherit from anything other than an abstract interface.

Answer (score 0):

In implict inlining the inline member function is defined within the class definition.the keyword inline is not used